# Determine if the sequence $\{a_n\}:a_n=(-3)^n$ is an increasing or a decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine if the sequence $\{a_n\}:a_n=(-3)^n$ is an increasing or a decreasing sequence.

The $(n+1)^{st}$ term is $a_{n+1}=(-3)^{n+1}.$ So $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\dfrac{(-3)^{n+1}}{(-3)^n}=\dfrac{(-3)^n(-3)^1}{(-3)^n}=-3<1.$ Doesn't this mean that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for every $n$ which obviously isn't true? The sequence looks like $-3,9,-27,81...,$ so it isn't monotonic, but why the usual method tells us else? We can use it if $a_n\ne0$ for every $n$ which holds here.

Comment: Why would $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$ imply $a_{n+1} < a_n$ ?

Comment: Well, it means that the numerator $<$ than the denominator, doesn't it?

Comment: No, for example, $\frac{2}{-1}<1$ but $2>-1$.

Comment: So, this method doesn't work? How does the solution look like then?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the sequence is $\{ a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} := \{(-3)^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Now, as mentioned earlier, $$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1 \implies a_{n+1}<a_n \quad \text{For any }n \in \mathbb{N} $$
holds if each $a_i >0$, for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$. But one thing to add here is the behavior of certain sub-sequences of the sequence $\{a_n\}$.

Note that the **even subsequence** is $\{ a_{2k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} :=\{(-3)^{2k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}=\{3^{2k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, **increasing**.

and the **odd subsequence** is $\{ a_{2k+1}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} :=\{(-3)^{2k+1}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}=\{-3^{2k+1}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, **decreasing**.

(This observation of the even and odd subsequences come in handy many times, in many problems)

Answer (score 0):

It is because $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$ does not tell you the sequence is decreasing.

What we would all like to do is to multiply both side by $a_n$, but **WE CAN'T**, since $a_n$ is not necessarily positive !

So $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$ does not imply $a_{n+1} < a_n$.